# fetching parent entity attribute value into child entity Plugin

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-dynamics

How can I fetch parent entity attribute value into Plugin which was written on creation of chile entity & make some calculation & again assign same to that parent entity attribute?

Comment: put the code that you try.. or your classes..

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I would do it in a plugin by creating a plugin library using the SDK in Visual Studio....

1st: Create an Organization Service using the plugins context.

```
IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
```

2nd: Call service.Retrieve() and pass the guid of the parent record

```
Entity ent = service.Retrieve(); //pass the guid and parent entity logical name
```

3rd: Grab that value from the retrieved entity data

```
var number = ent["attribute name you want"];
```

4th: Do the calculation

```
number = number * 100;
```

5th: Call service.Update() and pass the parent record with the new fields calculated value

```
ent["attribute name you want"] = number;
service.Update(ent);
```

then its just a matter of deploying your plugin to CRM.